# ZipArchive::open() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given

Tags: php, zip

```
$fver = str_replace(".","a",$arrMatches[1]);
$download = "ENU2v" . $fver . ".zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($download, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) 
{
    die ("An error occurred creating your ZIP file.");
}
```

The following code fails with the error in the question title.
But, if we change the first line to:

```
$download = "ENU2v.zip";
```

Then it does work. Where is the error? What goes wrong?

Comment: `var_dump($download); var_dump(file_exists($download));`

Comment: string(24) "ENU2v2a0a2a0.zip", and this file doesn't yet exist...

Comment: so most likely `$arrMatches` doesn't contain what you expect. If it's created from a regex, you might need to fix this.

Comment: @this.lau_ you were right, the regex is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
$fver = str_replace(".","a",$arrMatches[1]);
$download = "ENU2v" . $fver . ".zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($download, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res !== TRUE) {
    die ("An error occurred creating your ZIP file. Code: " . $res);
}
```

What is the error code?

Error Codes:

- ZIPARCHIVE::ER_EXISTS - 10 ( File already exists. )
- ZIPARCHIVE::ER_INCONS - 21 ( Zip archive inconsistent. )
- ZIPARCHIVE::ER_INVAL - 18 ( Invalid argument. )
- ZIPARCHIVE::ER_MEMORY - 14 ( Malloc failure. )
- ZIPARCHIVE::ER_NOENT - 9 ( No such file. )
- ZIPARCHIVE::ER_NOZIP - 19 ( Not a zip archive. )
- ZIPARCHIVE::ER_OPEN - 11 ( Can't open file. )
- ZIPARCHIVE::ER_READ - 5 ( Read error. )
- ZIPARCHIVE::ER_SEEK - 4 ( Seek error. )

Comment: Thanks for your help, though it was a complicated regex issue. I got it.